# Displaying one table data with respect to other table

Tags: php, oracle, rightnow-crm, roql

[image]

I'm stuck with this problem. I have 2 tables, `Invoice` and `Invoice_Lines`. I want to display my table in such a fashion that `Invoice` lines should be displayed below their respective Invoices. Here is my code:

```
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM Invoice";
        $roql_result_set = RightNow\Connect\v1_2\ROQL::query($queryString);

        echo "<table class=\"responstable\"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Account</th><th>Contact</th><th>Display Order</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Date Updated</th></tr>"; 
        while($roql_result = $roql_result_set->next())
        {
            while ($row = $roql_result->next())
            {   
                $lines = "SELECT * FROM Invoice_lines";
                $result_set = RightNow\Connect\v1_2\ROQL::query($lines);
                while($result = $result_set->next())
                {
                    while ($line = $result->next())
                    {                       
                        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . $line['ID'] ."</a></td><td><a href=\"#\">" . $line['Invoice'] . "</a></td><td>" . $line['Line_Number'] ."</td><td>" . $line['DisplayOrder'] . "</td></tr>"; 

                        $ctime = date('F j, Y' , strtotime($row['CreatedTime']));
                        $utime = date('F j, Y' , strtotime($row['UpdatedTime']));

                        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . $row['ID'] ."</a></td><td><a href=\"#\">" . $row['Account'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['Contact'] ."</td><td>" . $row['DisplayOrder'] ."</td><td>" . $ctime ."</td><td>" .$utime. "</td></tr>";  
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: can you show your expected output format?

Comment: I added image of present output above,. I want those 2 tables to be displayed in one table,. Please check my question for image.

Comment: First learn how to join 2 tables within sql using join. Then loop through the single dataset containing data from both tables.

Comment: Its not like how we do in Mysql or phpmyadmin,. This is an object designer  in oracle right CX, Normal Mysql doesn't works, I'm using ROQL here.

Comment: formatting & grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this,

```
SELECT Invoice.*, Invoice_lines.* 
  FROM Invoice
  LEFT JOIN Invoice_lines ON Invoice.ID = Invoice_lines.Invoice
   ORDER BY Invoice.Display_order, Invoice_lines.Display_order
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JOIN query here to construct a single resultset with content from both tables. A query like this will do the trick for you

```
SELECT Invoice.*, Invoice_lines.* 
  FROM Invoice
  LEFT JOIN Invoice_lines ON Invoice.ID = Invoice_lines.Invoice
   ORDER BY Invoice.Display_order, Invoice_lines.Display_order
```

But, please don't treat this query as a magic spell. Instead, learn how to use this core feature of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any exposure to MySQL through OSvC or its APIs.  That tag should be removed from the question.  The question is specific to `OSvC` (Oracle Service Cloud) and `ROQL`, which is application-layer specifc, not database specific.

If you have the tables joined through a relationship in the object designer as a parent and child, then you would use the ROQL join syntax, which is [explained in detail in the docs](https://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/august2015/Connect_PHP/Content/Connect%20for%20PHP%20API/RightNow%20Object%20Query%20Language/ROQL%20Tabular%20Query.htm).  Joins are implied inner joins when using ROQL, but you can set outer joins as well.  Assuming you want to get all invoice lines for contact 1234, and your Invoice object has a `Contact` relationship and a relationship titled `Invoice_lines`, then queryCSV would look something like this:

```
SELECT I.ID as InvoiceID, I.Invoice_lines.* FROM Invoice I WHERE I.Contact = 1234
```

Query Object (`queryObject` method) syntax would be slightly different since you do not specify columns, but I would use query in your case since you are outputting the data in a tabular format:

```
SELECT I, Invoice_lines FROM Invoice I WHERE I.Contact = 1234
```

You'll need to account for the 10,000 row limit in your logic; you might need a loop that pages through the results if you intend to show more than 10k rows on a page.

Also, it looks like you're merging view and controller code in your example.  This is bad practice.  You should be performing your queries from a model, returning the results of your query to the controller to pass to the view.  The view would simply iterate through the array of results to display your table.